# set backbone to point to an external endpoint

Tags: web-services, backbone.js, endpoint

In backbone, how can I point my entities to an external endpoint?

For example, my app is running on http://myapp.com

And I want it to use the followgin rest web service

http://external.com/api/rest/xxxx

I tried with [urlRoot](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-urlRoot) property but it doesn't seem to work that way

```
Sagan.FeatureModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: "New Feature",
    parent: "",
    enabled: false
  },
  urlRoot: 'http://localhost:9001/',
  url: 'features'
});
```

For testing purposes the app is hosted on localhost:9000, and the external webservice at localhost:9001.

backbone seems to still be pointing at localhost:9000 instead of 9001

Comment: Show us how are you using `urlRoot`.

Comment: @opensas Does the service respond a `model JSON` or `collection JSON`. If it is a collection then set the exact end point url as collection URL

Comment: added a sample showing how I'm trying to do it with urlRoot

Comment: Just use urlRoot don't use url using url causes it to send the request to the source of the script. Thou you will probably get problems with "XMLHttpRequest cannot load $REMOTE. Origin $LOCAL is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: Thanks Alexander, do you know some way to overcome the Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem?

Comment: @opensas How do you manage to switch back and forth of Url between testing local and production environment for all modals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you are setting customs `urlRoot` and `url` properties for the Model.

Setting up custom `url` property will make your custom `urlRoot` to be ignored due this property is used in the *default* `url` behavior, look on the [Model.url documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-url).

If you want your Model to use the *endpoint* `http://external.com/api/rest/features` just add it to the `urlRoot` and keep the `url` untouched:

```
urlRoot: "http://external.com/api/rest/features"
```

It will create routes like this:

```
GET http://external.com/api/rest/features/1
```

For fetching the Model with id 1.

Comment: Thanks, it worked... Now it's sending an OPTIONS request method instead of DELETE, but that's another problem, and quite possibly another stackoverflow question ;-)

Comment: What is trying your browser is ask for a server validation for an access from another _domain_. Search for [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) I'm sure you'll find plenty info in StackOverflow. Luck!.