# How to set API path in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here is an example Backbone api call:

```
var BookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/books'
});
```

How do you set the url path proceeding '/book' in order to tell backbone which remote server to call before performing the function?

```
urlRoot: 'domain.com/books'
```

does not work

Tried this - using anonymous functions:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
   urlRoot: function(){
      return 'http://apiurl.com/user';
   }
});
```

Comment: tried "urlRoot: function() { return what_ever_remote_server+"/boook"; }" ??

Comment: No, so I have to create a function within the json object? Is there a simpler way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: yep, just tried that - didnt work :(

Comment: How do you get any simpler than a one-line anonymous function?

Comment: If it doesn't work it's because of some syntax error.  Post the code you tried.  Also, use `url`, not `urlRoot`.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/petok/1/watch  Hit Run and see the alert!

Comment: Updated my question with the method I tried T Nguyen, thanks.

Comment: ok when I do book.url() it seems to return the correct path, not sure why backbone is not returning the object after the request is made...have managed to get it to work with an API helper I've created.

Comment: Isn't it a cross domain problem ?

Comment: Found out that the problem is 2 fold. 1) Using Alloy/titanium, doesn't have a rest adapter in built has some troubles with pure backbone.js and 2)  you have to call a fetch object, upon success it will return the object. Still looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot : function() {
        return window.location+'/books'; 
  }
});

var solaris = new Book({id: "1083-lem-solaris"});

console.log(solaris.url());
```

If you want to do some dynamic manipulation, use above snippet else

```
urlRoot : 'http://domain.com/books'
```

is sufficient.

This would be helpful

[set backbone to point to an external endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714725/set-backbone-to-point-to-an-external-endpoint?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks guys, it is working - but it is not returning the object after I make an api call solaris.save for example

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before: [set backbone to point to an external endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714725/set-backbone-to-point-to-an-external-endpoint)

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot : 'http://domain.com/books'
});
```

You don't need a function.